# How to enter text in uppercase?

Tags: textfield, vaadin

I need enter text only at uppercase. How can I do it in vaadin with TextField?
I need that text is really uppercase not only visualy using styles....

Answer (score 5):

An easy way to achieve this is to set the style and change the string to uppercase by yourself.

Here's the VAADIN code:

```
TextField donut = new TextField();
donut.setStyleName("upMeBro");
this.addComponent(donut);
```

Set the css file like this:

```
.v-textfield-upMeBro {
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

After a event is fired (User typed in text, Button is clicked, etc.) you can easily modify the string to uppercase with native java:

```
System.out.println(donut.getValue().toString().toUpperCase());
```

Comment: I'd prefer this solution, since it doesn't need any communication between client and server (until the button is clicked)

Comment: Yes it looks nice, but I am not sure how it works with data binding. I have container connected to Form. It use data binding and there is no get/set value. Probably I can add setValue to lost focus or commit button press.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to solve your problem is wroten by "user810595". But if your do not want to use custom styles in your application you can use this code:

```
    final TextField field = new TextField();
    field.setImmediate(true);

    field.addListener(new TextChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void textChange(TextChangeEvent event) {
            String text = event.getText();
            field.setValue(text.toUpperCase());

                    //TODO: do some actions if needed
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thank you. This is works but have some side efect. When I type characters it is displayed in lowercase and after some pause in typping it is changed to uppercase. Unfortunatelly the carret position is set to end of text. It is not correct behavoir when I edit some text.

Comment: If your form created using POJO object your always can write on field getter something like this: 
public class Object{
private String id;

public String getId(){
return this.id.toUpperCase();
}
}
If you will use this code, on server side you will get string in upper case all time and for user UI part you can use custom css style with wrote "user810595".

Answer (score 1):

Well this is my try:

code

```
public class UpperTextField extends TextField {


public UpperTextField() {
    addStyleName("upper-case");
}

@Override
protected String getInternalValue() {
    return super.getInternalValue() != null ? super.getInternalValue().toUpperCase() : super.getInternalValue();
}

}
```

css

```
.upper-case{
text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a converter. Just like you would convert a field from String to Int using the `StringToIntConverter`, you could try using the `StringToUpperCaseStringConverter` and then bind it.

Answer (score 0):

in event keyreleased you write

```
private void jTxtNoRincKeyReleased(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt)
{
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    jTxtNoRinc.setText(jTxtNoRinc.getText().toUpperCase());
}
```

jTxtNoRinc : Component's Name

it's simple

Answer (score -1):

I would say ..

```
<input id="yourid" style="**text-transform: uppercase**" type="text" />
```